# How to inherit Width to children elements

Tags: wpf, button, panel

I have 12 Buttons in for example one DockPanel. My question is how to inherit the Width of my DockPanel to the Buttons, so that they all have the same Width

```
        <DockPanel Width="1200" Height="30">
            <Button Width="100" Content="Januar"    />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Februar"   />
            <Button Width="100" Content="März"      />
            <Button Width="100" Content="April"     />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Mai"       />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Juni"      />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Juli"      />
            <Button Width="100" Content="August"    />
            <Button Width="100" Content="September" />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Oktober"   />
            <Button Width="100" Content="November"  />
            <Button Width="100" Content="Dezember"  />
        </DockPanel>
```

When im changing the width of my Dockpanel i want to change the width of the buttons too..

I know..

> Width={Binding ElementName=dockpanel1, Path=Width}

.. but i have to do take this width / 12.

Comment: you an use your binding example with a converter, convertparameter 12 and with ActualWidth instead of width or you can create a buttonstyle for your width

Comment: i think @blindmeis gave you right answer

Comment: i builded a converter, which worked, but then i see the answer from @Clemens, and i think thats better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UniformGrid` instead of a `DockPanel`:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" Width="1200" Height="30">
    <Button Content="Januar"    />
    <Button Content="Februar"   />
    <Button Content="März"      />
    <Button Content="April"     />
    <Button Content="Mai"       />
    <Button Content="Juni"      />
    <Button Content="Juli"      />
    <Button Content="August"    />
    <Button Content="September" />
    <Button Content="Oktober"   />
    <Button Content="November"  />
    <Button Content="Dezember"  />
</UniformGrid>
```